# why the system ask state/province is required field twice

Tags: magento

customer register the address and prompt state/province is required field, twice times. I selected yes in state option Display not required State. and got rid of one message, and state/province field appear. but system still give out message state/province is required field.

Comment: Can you show us either your code or screens?

Comment: I don't know where is code and how to attach screen picture?